# How to store filesystem information in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, filesystems

I need to create a virtual filesystem.
Basically I want give user an input to create / modify / delete files with the attributes which they will provide - Filename, size, foldername.
Files are stored inside a folder.

So basically I want to store the above information in an array / or in data structure in way that I can retrieve back and give summary -
XYZ file is stored in Folder7
DYT file is stored in Folder 8

User can now move XYZ file to folder 8 or he can delete it. These are not real files, just a virtual filenames/data points created when the program runs.

Additionally I want to store these files depending on their size during input in blocks. e.g. -
if I create array with 100 blocks and 1 block = 1mb. I create a file with 3MB, that means it will consume 3 blocks and I can retrieve information that a[0], a[1], a[2] has file xyz.

Basically I am creating a file system.

What would be the best way to store this information and then retrieve it easily for summary.

I want to do all of this in typescript. I dont want to use any filesystem api. I need to build a virtual model.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I haven't tried it yet tho.

```
const BLOCK_SIZE = 1e6;

interface VNode {
    name: string;
    parent: VFolder;
}

class VFile implements VNode {
    name: string;
    parent: VFolder;
    private _data: Buffer[];

    constructor(name: string, data: Buffer = Buffer.alloc(0)) {
        this.name = name;

        this._data = new Array(Math.ceil(data.byteLength/BLOCK_SIZE));
        for (let i = 0; i < data.byteLength; i+=BLOCK_SIZE) {
            this._data.push(data.slice(i, i+BLOCK_SIZE));
        }
    }

    get size() {
        return (this._data.length-1)*BLOCK_SIZE + (this._data.length === 0 ? 0 : this._data[this._data.length-1].byteLength);
    }

    delete() {
        this._data = [];
        if (this.parent === null) return true;
        return this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }

}

class VFolder implements VNode {
    name: string;
    parent: VFolder;
    private _childs: VNode[];

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    addChild(node: VNode) {
        node.parent = this;
        this._childs.push(node);
    }

    removeChild(node: VNode) {
        const index = this._childs.indexOf(node);
        if (index === -1) return false;
        this._childs.splice(index, 1)[0].parent = null;
        return true;
    }

}

const root = new VFolder("/");
root.addChild(new VFile("testfile123.txt", Buffer.from("mystring datatatat", "utf-8")));
```

Still needs some function to read or modify data later on...

Comment: there's an error in your code at Parent statement - VFolder